# Структура проекта Intellij Idea отображает переменные

Tags: java, intellij-idea

Скачивал несколько раз проект, но все равно ни чего не меняется. В  проекта, под классами появились переменные и директория "reversbot.services" была под классом Main. Настройка и сброс не помогают. Пробовал через Project Settings module, но делаю только хуже. Подскажите пожалуйста, что я делаю не так?

[image: HarTr]

А вот так в папке, в ней все нормально.

[image: Norm]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19136625/how-to-change-package-view-in-intellij

Comment: @Roman-StopRUaggressioninUA, помогло. Я чего то сам видимо на нажимал.

Comment: Прикольно. Это может быть удобно, на самом деле - например сразу из дерева переходить на нужный метод.